# Issues importing components

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-3.x

I am trying to import the material design component "top app bar" but when I put the following code in:

```
import {MDCTopAppBar} from '@material/top-app-bar/mdc-top-app-bar';
```

I get the following error code:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@material/top-app-bar/mdc-top-app-bar". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Any guidance on this would be appreciated. I am also very new to Polymer 3 coming from version 2 and am not used to using npm to install components and the new way of referencing so any resources on the topic that might be useful would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
import {MDCTopAppBar} from '@material/top-app-bar/mdc-top-app-bar';
```

to

```
import {MDCTopAppBar} from '@material/top-app-bar/index';
```

And to import `Style`:

```
<style>
   @import "@material/top-app-bar/mdc-top-app-bar";
</style>
```

Comment: thank you this worked for me. I have put the following code in:
          <header class="mdc-top-app-bar mdc-top-app-bar--fixed">
        RPS IMS
      </header>

however the styling does not seem to be working. I have added this line to the style tag but it doesn't seem to be importing again:

@import "@material/top-app-bar/mdc-top-app-bar";

TIA

Comment: I have tried that line for styling but it is not working

Comment: I am actually getting this error in the console:

Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html

Comment: I am getting this error message from Safari:
Did not parse stylesheet at 'http://localhost:8081/@material/top-app-bar/mdc-top-app-bar' because non CSS MIME types are not allowed in strict mode.
http://localhost:8081/favicon.ico

Answer (score 0):

You can use `require` library, which doesn't need to mention path.

Only the package name is sufficient.

```
var MDCTopAppBar = require('@material');
```